# Как в python получить доступ к переменной из другой функции

Tags: python

Стоит задача написать телеграм-бот. Есть библиотека https://github.com/unmonoqueteclea/calendar-telegram для работы с календарем. В результате нажатия на дату календаря я получаю переменную date с выбранной датой. Как теперь использовать эту переменную в другой функции, например для получения данных из базы за этот день?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['calendar'])
def get_calendar(message):
    now = datetime.datetime.now() #Current date
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    date = (now.year, now.month)
    current_shown_dates[chat_id] = date #Saving the current date in a dict
    markup = create_calendar(now.year, now.month)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пожалуйста, выберите дату", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data[0:13] == 'calendar-day-')
def get_day(call):
    chat_id = call.message.chat.id
    saved_date = current_shown_dates.get(chat_id)
    if(saved_date is not None):
        day = call.data[13:]
        date = datetime.date(int(saved_date[0]), int(saved_date[1]), int(day))
        bot.send_message(chat_id, date)
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, text="Выбрана дата")

    else:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Что-то пошло не так...')
        pass
```

## моя функция где я хочу использовать date

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['osmotry'])
def inspections(message):
    get_calendar(message)
    if (здесь переменная date) is not None:
        # подключение к базе данных
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='egekjgh', passwd='enqkjenjeknb', db='eklmel')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = """select...и здесь, я хочу использовать переменную date из функции get_day()
```

Answer (score 1):

Переменная `date` является локальной для функции `get_day()`, она не существует вне вызова `get_day()` поэтому вы не можете к ней обратиться из `inspections()` функции.

Вы можете определить функцию: `date_for(chat_id)` и использовать её в обоих функциях, к примеру как: `date = date_for(call.message.chat.id)`

Comment: можно пример кода?

Comment: Для ясности ответа на ваш вопрос ("как получить доступ") -- *нельзя*. Если не ясно как выделить вычисления `date` из `get_day()` в отдельную функцию, задайте отдельный вопрос.