# Нужно выделить вычисление переменной, для использования ее в других функциях

Tags: python-3.x

В моем тeлеграм-боте есть такая функция, которая обрабатывает нажатие на кнопку с датой. В результате мы получаем переменную `date`.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data[0:13] == 'calendar-day-')
def get_day(call):
    chat_id = call.message.chat.id
    saved_date = current_shown_dates.get(chat_id)
    if(saved_date is not None):
        day = call.data[13:]
        date = datetime.date(int(saved_date[0]), int(saved_date[1]), int(day))
        bot.send_message(chat_id, date)
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, text="Выбрана дата")

    else:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Что-то пошло не так...')
        pass
```

Необходимо выделить вычисление `date` из `get_day()` в отдельную функцию, например: `date_for(chat_id)` для использования её в других функциях, к примеру как: `date = date_for(call.message.chat.id)`
Предистория обсуждения находится здесь [ru.stackoverflow.com/q/823397/23044](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/823397/23044)

Comment: Если нужно выделить в отдельную функцию, то что мешает?

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/vse-o-funkciyax-i-ix-argumentax.html

Comment: В вашем случае можно вообще ничего не менять, а просто дописать в конце ``return date``. Или лучше переименовать (чтобы бы была отдельная функция), удалить лишние строчки и так же дописать в конце ``return date``.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data[0:13] == 'calendar-day-')
def get_day(call):
    chat_id = call.message.chat.id
    bot.register_next_step_handler(call, date_for)
def date_for(chat_id):
    saved_date = current_shown_dates.get(chat_id)
    if(saved_date is not None):
        day = call.data[13:]
        date = datetime.date(int(saved_date[0]), int(saved_date[1]), int(day))
        bot.send_message(chat_id, str(date))
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, text="Выбрана дата")
        return date
    else:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Ошибка')
        pass
```

Теперь при вызове

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['inspections'])
def inspections(message):
    get_calendar(message)
    date = date_for(call.message.chat.id)
```

выдает ошибку:

chat_id = message.chat.id

AttributeError: 'CallbackQuery' object has no attribute 'chat'